# Explicit intent with a non-class BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that I want to update a number in the display on an activity. I have an explicit intent already set up, that I use to start the activity if it isn't running, and I've added a broadcast receiver to my activity in the form:

```
    public BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(LOG_NAME, "Received broadcast");
        }
   };
```

But it never receives any broadcasts. I suspect this is because my explicit intent is to MyClass.class (which is not a receiver itself) rather than the actual receiver, which is a member.
Does anyone have suggestions on whether this is possible with an explicit intent? I could use an implicit intent, but that seems a little wasteful as this is only ever going to a particular class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you could have a separate BroadcastReceiver which receives the explicit broadcast and updates a shared preference, and your activity contain an onSharedPreferenceChangeListener, which would do the updating of the activity.

Comment: This would be a very neat way of doing it. In the meantime, I've done it without using an explicit intent (https://github.com/spookypeanut/Wake-Me-At/blob/master/src/uk/co/spookypeanut/wake_me_at/Alarm.java), I may well switch to the way you suggest here in future.

Answer (score 0):

That's way it won't work. You should have your BroadcastReceiver as a separate class.

Comment: How do I then get it to update a value in the gui of an activity though?